# Define a hierarchy of model classes in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, model, class-hierarchy

By default CakePHP has a `AppModel` class and every model of an application inherits from it. A common design pattern to share logic between models is to create a behavior and configure a model to `$actAs` that behavior.

But what if I wanted to introduce a hierarchy of model classes like this?:

```
AppModel
  |__ Vehicle
        |__ Car
        |__ Bike
        |__ Helicopter
```

I have tried to create a `Vehicle` class that inherits from `AppModel`, and then every children class inherits from `Vehicle`. But CakePHP tells me it cannot find the class `Vehicle`.

How could I make this and where in the CakePHP directory tree should I create `Vehicle`?

Thanks!

Comment: i like this idea so i search a little bit. There is a way to implement this, explained [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/eldonbite/2008/09/18/subclass-behavior) Haven't try it yet though... Other way will be to mess with the class_registry file or the app class that are in charge of the load... but i don't recomend it

Comment: I came across that behavior as well, but it seems that it tries to mimic the native behavior of class inheritance at application level. I think it's overkill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it should not be a problem to do so
you only need to make sure you app::import() the "parent model" before you declare it.
or what did you do that the model cannot be found?

If I do sth like that I use a lib to be my "vehicle"
it does not have to be a model in the model directory

e.g. App::import('Lib', 'Vehicle');

Vehicle extends AppModel

Car extends Vehicle

Comment: Correct, I believe; cake will not know automatically where to find the Vehicle class, without you tell it manually using import().